# How to check if a selenium webelement has no sub tag in it which holds 'text'

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have a web element that sometimes delay loading or do not load properly. But when it loads, it will have a number as text element. I need this text to check and do some process later. I am able to extract this text and convert as number when this webelement is loaded properly. When it loads, there will be a  tag element inside and it will consist a text as well. (Just for understanding what I am trying to explain, showing you an image of it. I have copy pasted code below) My aim is to extract this text '201515' below.

[image]

There are series of elements and few are properly loaded and where as few are not. This is explained as:

[image]

But when the DOM does not load, the program just throws an error and my program aborts. Because it is not loaded properly, I will not have any anchor tag element and hence no text element item. Shown as below:

[image]

At this time if I am checking as my `webelement.text`, it neither gives none or null value. Is there any possiblity how I can make it load properly or precisely check if there is no element text present, make it load and redo the operation. Or is my understanding wrong and it doesnot load ever at all?

My python code:

```
for element_index in range(count_of_divs):
    index = str(element_index + 1)    # in web elements, it is one based index
    xpath = '//*[@id="wrapped_grid"]/div[5]/div/div[' + index + ']/div[2]'
    test_id = WebDriverWait(self.login.driver, self.login.DELAY).until(
                            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xpath)))      
     # Get the Test ID number
    
    time.sleep(0.1)
    if test_id.text != "":
       test_id_num = int(test_id.text)
       currentpage_test_ID_list.append(test_id_num
```

)

This shows I have some discrepancy and text is blank. But how can I make this element load properly and get the text.

Just for clear picture understanding, I am also adding screenshots of DOM. I copy pasted code above and it is not screenshot. Picture is only for understanding how it looks.

I appreciate all your feedback/support in this

Comment: What's the `XPath` that you are using?

Comment: @supputuri : Edited the code with xpath

Comment: Can you please replace the xpath with `//*[@id="wrapped_grid"]/div[5]/div/div[' + index + ']//div[@field-name="test_id"]/a` and check it works. I am not sure about the `//*[@id="wrapped_grid"]/div[5]/div/div[' + index + ']/` part as we don't have the complete html in the post.

Comment: Yes. That is also same as //*[@id='wrapped_grid']/div[5]/div/div[' + index + ']/div[2]/a. This is much simpler. I can locate it. But my problem is how should I solve this "loading" as highlighted in the screenshot. Is there a possibility that I can load it so that I can get the text?

Comment: Does the data load dynamically as you scroll the page down?

Comment: Yes it does. It takes 0.1 seconds to load the new data after scrolling

Comment: Sometimes it takes more than 0.5 seconds.. Its just an approximate load time

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225788/discussion-between-supputuri-and-priya).

Comment: Priya can you please join the chat.